# How do i run a ServiceStack console project as a Windows Service?

Tags: windows-services, servicestack

I have create a ServiceStack console application that works great, but of course, I have to leave it running after triggering it from a command prompt.  I want to run this as a Windows Service.

I'm reviewing this wiki page which states that you can run SS as a Windows Service.

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Self-hosting

I was not totally clear on how to do this.  This StarterTemplate is referenced from 2 years ago.  Do I clone this project and then copy my code into it?

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/tree/master/src/StarterTemplates/WinServiceAppHost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a **ServiceStack Windows Service Empty** project in [ServiceStackVS VS.NET Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5bd40817-0986-444d-a77d-482e43a48da7).

Otherwise you can clone the WinService project, and create a new Windows Service project from Visual Studio and copy the approach in [Program.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/StarterTemplates/WinServiceAppHost/Program.cs).

A more recent ServiceStack Windows Service project is the [Razor Rockstars](http://razor.servicestack.net/) website running in a [Windows Service Host](https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars/tree/master/src/RazorRockstars.WinService), the template of which was based on the ServiceStack.Examples Starter template.

Comment: Hi, I don't understand the code in [Program.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/StarterTemplates/WinServiceAppHost/Program.cs). If it is a Windows Service, what does it mean `http://localhost:port`? It is not a web service.

Comment: @Love It's still running a self-hosted web service, it's just running inside a Windows Service.

Comment: So the template is `ServiceStack Windows Service Empty` when can create the project?

Answer (score 3):

I use topshelf to run a servicestack console app as a windows service.  It works really well for me. https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf

Comment: interesting, i've used TopShelf for other things.  So the end points show up just fine while running in the windows service?

Comment: I've not had any problems.  My deployment script includes modifications to the acl to enable the user that the service is running as to use port 80:  netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:80/ user=XXX\XXXXXX

Comment: @MikeT Any examples of this?